# XML::Compile::SOAP - convert response into hash

Tags: xml, web-services, perl, soap

I'm quite new to SOAP and XML::Compile and most of the examples that I could google end with the SOAP call without much explanation on how to process the response.

Is there an easy way to convert SOAP response to hash ?

here is my code

....

```
my ($response, $trace) = $call->($request);
my $content=$trace->response->decoded_content();
my $out=XML::Hash->new()->fromXMLStringtoHash($content)
```

but I'm getting the following error:

junk after document element at line 4, column 0, byte 11177 at /usr/lib/perl5

Looking at what was returned from the server:

< soap:Envelope .....

**ba8**

...< /soap:Envelope>

0

I'm not sure how the 'ba8' get into the response as once you remove it looks like a complete and valid response.

Answer (score 0):

The SOAP response should be a hash. trace is an object that lets you get the HTTP request and/or response, but you should not need to look at that except to debug.

```
use Data::Dumper;

...
print Dumper $response;
```

Comment: $response is coming back empty - probably because the soap response is not a complete XML - I keep seeing either ba8 or 1ff8 that cut through what is otherwise a correct response in trace - is there some sort of encoding problem with the response because there is no reason why those lines should be there.

Comment: Also looking at the trace of HHTP response -Client-Transfer-Encoding: chunked which tells me it is encoding issue as all weird lines are coming with the constant frequency

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem was with the known bug in *Net::HTTP* - everything works fine now after I upgraded it to the latest version along with *LWP::UserAgent* [just in case].